# Get all comments of a certain user with Facebook FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I know its not possible to do so with the graph `API`, but is it possible to do so with `FQL` ?

I was thinking about something along these lines:

```
SELECT object_id FROM comment
WHERE id in (
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
) 
AND fromid = me()
```

but unfortunately it's not going anywhere. Tried searching other posts but nobody came up with a good solution yet.